# Powershell - join variables with delimiter even if some vars are $null

Tags: powershell

There are some string vars: var1,var2,var3,var4

Some of them can be $null in any time

I need to join them in var1;var2;var3;var4 but in case of $null i will have something awful like var1;;;var4 instead of var1;var4

Any way to do it? Maybe some param for -join ? Or some way no filter them in one line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oops looks like found solution here

var1,var2,var3,var4 -ne $null -join ';'

Comment: Nice, but please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).